# Set src file path into Dockerfile

Tags: docker

After compilation `.jar` file in:

`/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PROD__Backend-Build-Deploy/target/laplacelab-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

But old Dockerfile was run just from a folder with `.jar` and Dockerfile.

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11

VOLUME /tmp
ADD laplacelab-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar laplacelab-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /laplacelab-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/laplacelab-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Where I should change the path for new dir? Only in `ENTRYPOINT` line or `ADD` need to change too?
What should it be like to be for the new structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker can't access files outside of the Docker build context, so you will need to either move the file or specify the context in your build command, e.g.:

```
docker build -t foo:latest /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PROD__Backend-Build-Deploy/target/
```

If you do not have your Dockerfile in the same directory as your build context, you will need to specify its location using -f, like this:

```
docker build -t foo:latest -f ./Dockerfile /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PROD__Backend-Build-Deploy/target/
```

In Compose it can look something like this:

```
build:
  context: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PROD__Backend-Build-Deploy/target/
  dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
```